# MongoDB aggregate claculating the outdated collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on a social media app and I'm having this problem, I have a collection for friends to store friend requests and the relationship between users and everything works fine, but I'm working on a post('save') middleware and aggrgate pipeline to count the number of friends per user per process which also worked But the problem is aggrgate pipeline counting friends before update collection eg if user accepts friend request it counts friends without this new friend.

Is there any solution to this or best way to do it?

Here is the code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./userModel');

const FriendSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sender: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  recipient: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['pending', 'accepted', 'cancelled'],
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

FriendSchema.statics.calcFriends = async function (senderID, recipientID) {
  const senderIDstats = await this.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
          { sender: senderID, status: 'accepted' },
          { recipient: senderID, status: 'accepted' },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        count: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
  ]);
  const recipientIDstats = await this.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
          { sender: recipientID, status: 'accepted' },
          { recipient: recipientID, status: 'accepted' },
        ],
      },
    },

    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        count: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
  ]);

  await User.bulkWrite([
    {
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: senderID },
        update: {
          friendsCount: senderIDstats.length > 0 ? senderIDstats[0]?.count : 0,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: recipientID },
        update: {
          friendsCount:
            recipientIDstats.length > 0 ? recipientIDstats[0]?.count : 0,
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
};

FriendSchema.index({ sender: 1, recipient: 1 }, { unique: true });

FriendSchema.post('save', function () {
  this.constructor.calcFriends(this.sender, this.recipient);
});

const Friend = mongoose.model('Friend', FriendSchema);

module.exports = Friend;
```

Comment: i found out there's nothing wrong the problem is when i remove a friend document the middleware doesn't run so i added a post middleware for 'remove' and everything working fine